# Is it possible to use different colors on the same line / spline chart series?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to simulate a 'get range' function on a spline / line chart in high charts. but cant seem to find any examples out there.

So i thought i could fake it by using a different color for 'selected' range and non selected range.

Lets say i click a button, the chart recolors from 1st data to 5th data, while any data onwards i colored in a different colors.

i saw a few of zoom selections, but thats not quite what im trying to achieve. any help is appreciated.

i see that thresholds+negativecolor achieve something similar to what i want, but i want to be able to customize the range of which its a different color:http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.negativeColor

example show in the image here: 
[image]

Comment: You can use zones to specify different colors for the range - see info and examples in API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones

Comment: great! looks like something i can work with. thanks!